# Android studio for loop for simple calculation not working

Tags: java, database, android-studio, parse-platform

I want to retrive a list of data objects from Parse.com but I don't know how can you help me please

This is my code

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2015, 8, 12, 0, 0, 0);
    Calendar sswal = Calendar.getInstance();
    sswal.set(2015, 8, 12, 23, 30, 0);
    Date dd = cal.getTime();
    Date mok =sswal.getTime();
    final ParseObject[] most = new ParseObject[10];



    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RashedHospitalMonthSchedule");
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("appointDate", dd);
    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("appointDate", mok);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (parseObject == null) {
                Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
            } else {

                for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    most[i].getParseObject(String.valueOf(parseObject));
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

................

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't seen where is your `for loop`?

Comment: I re edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using getFirstInBackground() use findInBackground(). getFirstInBackground will only return 1 ParseObject while findInBackground() will return a list of ParseObjects.